# Centered title does not show up in Table of Contents in Rmarkdown

Tags: latex, r-markdown

Most reports in my area have the titles of new sections centered in bold. I can do this via a LaTex command (see example below).

However I really like the Table of Contents feature in Rmarkdown where it registers any text in the non-chunk portion of the .Rmd document beginning with at least one `#` as a heading and dutifully bolds it and places it in the table of contents.

The problem is that these titles are left-aligned.

I want my cake and to eat it too. I want a centre-aligned heading that shows up in the table of contents

.Rmd script illustrating the problem included below. Any solution to this problem would be much appreciated.

````
---
title: "A Problem With Centering Headings"
output: pdf_document
toc: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# This Title Shows Up In My TOC

\begin{center}\Large
\textbf{This Title Does Not Show Up in My TOC}
\end{center}

This is some text that is completely irrelevant to the example
````

Comment: Use LaTeX package `titlesec` to format the `\section` command? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8546/section-heading-centering-problem . Or even easier: `\usepackage{sectsty}` and then `\allsectionsfont{\centering}` . Alternativels you could define a new command like `\csection` to create single centered sections.

Comment: Thank you @ Martin Dabbel Ju Smelter that was very helpful. However now *all* the headings are centered. I didn't think hard enough about what I wanted in my description of my problem above. I need to be able to centre *some* of the headings (i.e. the main section headings like Introduction, Methods, Results) but have the second- and third-tier headings remain left-aligned. Do you know the command to turn it the `allsectionsfont{\centering}` function on and off again within the text of the document?

Comment: Actually I found it myself. See my answer below. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

I have done some reading of the `sectsty` package's documentation and this is the way it is done.

Step 1: include the `sectsty` package in your YAML metadata.

Step 2: At the beginning of the document specify how you would like the different tiered headings to be aligned within your document. `allsectionsfont{<command>}` applies the command in the curly braces to the first-tiered section headings (in Rmarkdown designated by a single `#`). `subsectionfont{<command>}` applies the command in the curly braces to second-tiered headings (designated by `##`), and `subsubsectionfont{<command>}` does the same to the third-tiered headings. AND all of these headings will show up in your TOC.

Note: `\raggedright` left-aligns and `\raggedleft` right aligns. Don't know why but that's the way it is.

See RMarkdown doc below

```
---
title: "No more problems With Centering Headings"
output: pdf_document
toc: yes
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{sectsty}
---

\allsectionsfont{\centering}
\subsectionfont{\raggedright}
\subsubsectionfont{\raggedleft}

# At last my main titles are centered

Now for some irrelevant text. 

## Second Tiered Titles are Automatically Left-aligned

Now for more text

### Third-tiered titles are automatically right-aligned

now some more text
```